# Advanced rails 4 database query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I have one problem with more advanced database queries. I'm using rails 4

I have a User model, each user has one location in location table.

Second table is user_friendships. There is fields user_id, friend_id, and friend id references user in user table. User has relationship with this table like this: each user has many friends and friendships.

```
class User

    has_one :location, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :user_friendships
    has_many :friends, through: :user_friendships

class user_friendship

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
```

Now I would like to display all user friendships who have relationship with this user, but only those friendships where friend has updated their location in past 20 minutes.

So I tried

```
time = params[:timestamp]
endtime = time.to_i - 1200
friends = UserFriendship.where(user_id: <user.id>)
updted = friends.include(:users).include(:location).where(updated_at: time..endtime)
```

or this

```
    friends = UserFriendship.where(user_id: <user.id>)
    updted = friends.include(:users).include(:location).where("created_at <= :start_date AND created_at >= :end_date",
{start_date: time, end_date: endtime})
```

but I'm getting this error: `wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)`, but the problem is that I don't even  know if that's right.

What I want to achieve is to find all user friendships, but only those friendships where friends have updated their location in past 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You have something like a `user has one location` relationship too, right?

Getting a user's friends:

```
user.friends
```

Getting friends who have updated their location within the last 20 minutes:

```
user.
friends.
joins(:locations).
where("#{Location.table_name}.updated_at >= ?", 20.minutes.ago)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but your answer showed me that I asked my question incorrectly. I'm sorry, I updated my question.

what I wanted to know Is how to find all user friendships in user_friendships table with friends who has updated their location in past 20 minutes.